# Problem in HtmlUnit API for Java (Headless Browser)?

Tags: java, htmlunit, headless, headless-browser

I am using HtmlUnit headless browser to browse this [webpage](http://www.ticketmaster.com/event/0B004354D90759FD?artistid=1073053&majorcatid=10002&minorcatid=207) (you can see the webpage to have a better understanding of the problem).

I have set the select's value to "1"

[image]

by the following commands

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_7);
    try {
        // Configuring the webClient
        webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.setCssEnabled(true);
        webClient.setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        webClient.setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.setActiveXNative(true);
        webClient.setAppletEnabled(true);
        webClient.setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

        // Adding listeners
        webClient.addWebWindowListener(new com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindowListener() {

            public void webWindowOpened(WebWindowEvent event) {
                numberOfWebWindowOpened++;
                System.out.println("Number of opened WebWindow: " + numberOfWebWindowOpened);
            }

            public void webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent event) {
            }

            public void webWindowClosed(WebWindowEvent event) {
                numberOfWebWindowClosed++;
                System.out.println("Number of closed WebWindow: " + numberOfWebWindowClosed);
            }
        });

        webClient.setWebConnection(new HttpWebConnection(webClient) {
            public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequestSettings settings) throws IOException {
                System.out.println(settings.getUrl());
                return super.getResponse(settings);
            }
        });

        CookieManager cm = new CookieManager();
        webClient.setCookieManager(cm);


        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.ticketmaster.com/event/0B004354D90759FD?artistid=1073053&majorcatid=10002&minorcatid=207");

        HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("quantity_select");
select.setSelectedAttribute("1", true);
```

and then clicked on the following button

[image]

by the following commands

```
HtmlButtonInput button = (HtmlButtonInput) page.getElementById("find_tickets_button");
HtmlPage captchaPage = button.click();
Thread.sleep(60*1000);
System.out.println("======captcha page=======");
System.out.println(captchaPage.asXml());
```

but even after clicking on the button and waiting for 60 seconds through the Thread.sleep() method, I am getting the same HtmlPage.

But when I do the same thing through real browser then I get the page that contains CAPTCHA.

I think I am missing something in the htmlunit.

Q1. Why am I not getting the same page (that contains CAPTCHA) through htmlunit's browser?

Comment: give the code with which you are creating your `webClient`

Comment: setting `BROWSER_VERSION` should set the User-Agent header. So perhaps monitor the HTTP headers sent by your browser on request, and those sent by your application (via a proxy) to see the difference.

Comment: I have tried that also. All request headers are same in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

The web form on that page requires the quantity_select drop-down to be filled in. You're attempting to do that in your code by assuming the drop-down is a select element. However, it's no longer a select element. Try using Firebug to inspect the drop-down and you'll see that JavaScript has replaced the select with a complex set of nested div elements.

If you figure out how to emulate each user click on the divs for that unusual drop-down then you should be able to submit the form.

Comment: Or you could also just try using firebug to figure out what the site wants for the form and emulate that for your request.  Can be easier to skip that step sometimes :-)